# Push hierarchical array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document:

```
{
  "_id":"575322d9585095d9929554ba",
  "Level1":{
    "Level2":[
      {
        "Level3a":{
          "Level4":{
            "Level5":{
              "name":"John",
              "surname":"Matthew"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Level3a":{
          "Level4":{
            "Level5":{
              "name":"Emma",
              "surname":"Jackson"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to insert the new name and surname at Level5. I tried the $push method but I got the error that the dotted field .. is not valid for storage:

```
db.names.update({ "_id":"575322d9585095d9929554ba" },
   {
     $push: {
      "Level1.Level2":
       { $each: [ { "Level3a.Level4.Level5.name": "Greg" },
                  { "Level3a.Level4.Level5.surname": "Cook" }] } } } )
```

It seems that push does not allow the inserting new data in hierarchical arrays or I am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with your query as `$each` is used to add multiple values to same array....

As we are going to add only one entry to array we don't need to use `$each`
so query looks like this:

```
db.vnenad.update({
    "_id" : "575322d9585095d9929554ba"
},
    {
    $push : {
        "Level1.Level2" : {
            "Level3a" : {
                "Level4" : {
                    "Level5" : {
                        "name" : "johnny",
                        "surname" : "rambo"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

as I was debbuging your query I decided to create variable with document to insert inside an array, then it was easier for me to adjust your query - please see below:

```
var doc = {
    "Level3a" : {
        "Level4" : {
            "Level5" : {
                "name" : "johnny",
                "surname" : "rambo"
            }
        }
    }
}

db.vnenad.update({
    "_id" : "575322d9585095d9929554ba"
},
    {
    $push : {
        "Level1.Level2" : doc
    }
})
```